STM32H7S3L8 Error
I am using STM32 Nucleo-144 development board with STM32H7S3L8 MCU.
I get this comment when trying to run code that cubeIDE generated initially: Break at address "0x800efb8" with no debug information available, or outside of program code. I did not change anything in the code or in the configuration.

I have no idea how to debug in this situation. Please assist me.
I have already set up a configuration on STM32F407G and want to transfer that project on H7 MCU to use its better capabilities. I have not even be able to set up and run the initial code.
Here is Disassembly

I have another question. Why are there separate Appli and Boot projects and why is there warning sign on Boot project?
Update:
I do not know what the exact cause was, but for some time the problem was solved. In cubeIDE target selector I always picked STM32H7S3L8H6 which is on Nucleo Development board. It generated boot project with a warning sign and had the problem I described before. Yesterday in target selector I picked MCU STM32H7S3L8H6H which does not have a board. This time cubeIDE gave me an option: "For this Cortex-M7 device, it is highly recommended to preconfigure the Memory protection Unit to optimize the Speculative Read access of the core". I selected "Yes". I do not know whether this was what solved the problem but after this it worked. I uploaded code and debuged it. Everything was running correct. However, it does not let me upload code anymore. The error I get is this Error: "No STM32 target found! If your product embeds Debug Authentication, please perform a discovery using Debug Authentication".

I edited question to include Disassembly

According to the RM0477 Reference manual for STM32H7Rx/7Sx Arm® -based 32-bit MCUs the address 0x800efb8 is within the FMC NAND Flash memory. Is a FMC NAND device connected to the STM32H7S3L8 and if so has it been programmed?

please show the disassembly as text, not as a picture

Had the same issue with my Nucleo-H7S3L8, using STM32H7S3L8H6H (instead of the one which is explicitely tied to this board) also works for me! Thank you for pointing it out.

@pyrho I am having another issue with STM32H7S3L8H6H MPU:
Do you have any clue about this?

@NicolasTsagareli Sorry this is beyond my expertise.

CubeIDE's generated code for Nucleo-H7S3L8 is faulty as far as I understand but if you choose MPU STM32H7S3L8 and configure it, then generated code works.
Fixed "target not found" error by pulling boot0 pin high. It is done by putting jumper on CN11's pin5 and pin7.

What is faulty, the address range of the executable code, or the default MCU of Nucleo? Please [edit] your answer to explain why the error message appears.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
